# clear value in Partial view(Multiple)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one patialview which is user two time

Parialview:

```
<divclass="row Address2">
    <divclass="col-sm-4">
        <divclass="md-form">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.StateId,Model.States,"--SelectState--",new{@id="addressState",@class="posT mdb-select",@autocomplete="off"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <divclass="col-sm-4">
        <divclass="md-form">
            <divclass="loader-div">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.City,new{@id="addressCity",@autocomplete="off",@class="form-control Clr"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <divclass="col-sm-4">
        <divclass="md-form">
            <divclass="loader-div">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Zipcode,new{@id="addressZipcode",@autocomplete="off",@class="form-control Clr",})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to Delete State and zipcode base on state dropdown change.

Suppose i select above dropdown then its should delete above or current div state and zipcode
if i select below dropdown than below state and zipcode should be delete.

But in my case when i select below dropdown that time its always clear above.
My java script as bellow.

```
$(".mdb-select").change(function(){
if($(this).closest('.Address2').find('#addressState').val()==''){

$(this).closest('.Address2').find('#addressCity').val("");
$(this).closest('.Address2').find('#addressZipcode').val("");

//$(this).parents('.Address2').find('#addressCity').val("");
//$(this).parents('.Address2').find('#addressZipcode').val("");
}
}
})
```

and i have bind partialview like this

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressPartial", feedback.AddressProperty, new ViewDataDictionary() { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "AddressProperty" } })

 and

 @Html.Partial("_AddressPartial", feedback.EscrowProperty, new ViewDataDictionary() { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "EscrowProperty" } })
```

and also try to remove by below JQ
 $(this).closest('.Address2').find('.Clr').val("");

but Result is same.

Comment: Your generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html (and your jquery selector will only ever select the first element with a specific `id`). And your generating duplicate `name` attribute so this could never bind correctly to a model anyway.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have update my question please see the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `HtmlFieldPrefix` correctly generates unique `id` attributes but your use of `new { @id=".." }` is overriding that and generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html, and your jquery selectors will only ever select the first one.

Change it to use class names and relative selectors instead

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateId, Model.States,"--SelectState--", new { @class="posT mdb-select", @autocomplete="off"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class="city form-control Clr", @autocomplete="off",})
@Html.TextBoxFor( m=> m.Zipcode, new {@class="zipcode form-control Clr", @autocomplete="off" })
```

Then the scripts becomes

```
$('.mdb-select').change(function() {
    var state = $(this).val();
    var container = $(this).closest('.Address2');
    container.find('.city').val('');
    container.find('.zipcode').val('');
});
```

As a side note, it easier to use an `EditorTemplate` to generate the controls. Assuming your class is `Address.cs`, then rename your partial to `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml` (ie to match the class name), and then in the main view it becomes

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AddressProperty)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EscrowProperty)
```